# Splitting a String in java using dynamic programming

Tags: java

i have tried to figure out how this code works, but i could not understand it, which is about splitting a String in different indexes using dynamic programming, and i am wondering if someone could help me out to understand it.

```
public int cMemoised(int[] z, int n) {
    int[][] savedValues = new int[n + 1][(int) Math.pow(2, n + 1) - 1];
    return cMemoisedRek(z, n, savedValues);
}

public int cMemoisedRek(int[] z, int n, int[][] savedValues) {
    if (z.length == 1) {
        savedValues[n][hash(z)] = n;
        return n;
    }
    if (z.length == 0) return 0;
    int zHash = hash(z);
    if (savedValues[n][zHash] != 0) return savedValues[n][zHash];
    int result = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < z.length; ++i) {
        int[] leftZ = new int[i];
        int[] rightZ = new int[z.length - i - 1];
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
            leftZ[j] = z[j];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < z.length; ++j)
            rightZ[j - i - 1] = z[j] - z[i];
        int currentValue = n + c(leftZ, z[i]) + c(rightZ, n - z[i]);
        if (currentValue < result)
            result = currentValue;
    }
    savedValues[n][zHash] = result;
    return result;
}
```

so we have here two Arrays, and i do under stand that we are using those tow Arrays in order to split the String but i wanna know what is going after that and why we are returning the result, is it the maximum number of copying the parts of the String .
i would be thankful for your help

Comment: Dynamic programming is mostly math, and arguably months / years of training. Its nothing you learn and understand in a day. Most programmers will never need it. I'd suggest you go over to leetcode.com and solve many DP problems until you get the hang of it.

Comment: The code you posted does not apply any string. Whatever it does, it seems the second method was intended to recurse, but it's not recursing anywhere. Since you do not provide any context or documentation, and no definition for the hash() and c() methods, your question is incomplete and I think not useful in stackoverflow